# Leaflet TimeDimension path line color

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to change the path line color and weight/stoke on Leaflet.TimDimension "Basic GeoJSON usage" example.

http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example17.html

I have went though their site and could not find anything, or over looked it. The only thing I found with a stroke option isn in example 8 (http://apps.socib.es/Leaflet.TimeDimension/examples/example8.html).

I also did a multi file search of the downloaded GIT repository for stroke and only came up with example #8.

I zoomed in on the map/line and inspected the code and found where stroke and width is generate;

```
<path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" d="M1034 157L1026 160L619 205L561 70L608 2L711 445L650 599L585 680L508 770"></path>
```

I mainly would like to not show the path line or set the width and stoke myself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a styling hack

```
<style>
    .leaflet-pane > svg path.leaflet-interactive {
        border-width: 0px !important; /* optional */
        stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important; /* color */
        stroke-opacity: .5 !important; /* transparency */
        stroke-width: 0 !important; /* line width */
        stroke-linecap: round !important; /*  */
        stroke-linejoin: round !important /*  */
    }
</style>
```

Still looking for a way to do it when setting it up with the plugin/javascript